# VBA Recompilation required

Tags: excel, vba, interface

I have an interface `IReadable` where I declare:

```
Public Function getFields() As Dictionary
End Function

Public Function getData()
End Function
```

The interface's instancing property is set to `publicNotCreatable`

I have an Excel sheet that implements this interface and these methods (details not important).

From module mApp, I apply the following code from a sub routine:

```
Dim oSheet As IReadable

Set oSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("tbl_deals") 'Compile error
```

When the VBA gets compiled via the menu Debug - Compile VBAProject, everything runs fine. Strangely, the code only gets run once.
If I try to run the code a second time, I get a `Type Mismatch` error.

In order to make the code run again, I need to switch the status of the interface to private and back, recompile, and the code runs again a single time (the second time, the code returns a type mismatch error again).

Any ideas on how to solve this problem, to make the code run stable without needing to recompile every time?

Edit: This is a strange problem. I thought it might have been related to pollution of the compiled code, but when re-creating the case in a new Excel workbook, the identical problem persists.

Comment: Where is it saying there is a type mismatch?

Comment: @MatthewD Where i set the sheet as interface (edited the code sample, put a comment behind the line)

Comment: did you try Dim oSheet As new IReadable

Comment: @newjenn Yes, tried that, didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code name of worksheet instead of displayed name:

[image]